# Exclude 'xmlns:xl' from the result node

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy a node from one XML file into another. To localize the place where to insert is I use a processing-instruction as placeholder. Everything works fine, but I don't need the `xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` in my output file, which is declared on the root element of the source file.

**XML from where the node is copied**:

```
<mei xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <respStmt xml:id="resp_1">
        <corpName xml:id="NMA-editors">
            <persName authURI="http://d-nb.info/gnd" authority="GND" codedval="119177978" label="MI-PID_58333" role="Editor" xml:id="HoLa">Howard Chandler Robbins Landon</persName>
        </corpName>
    </respStmt>
</mei>
```

**XML where the node is copied into**:

```
 <mei xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei">
    <respStmt>
        <?NMA-editors?>
    </respStmt>
</mei>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[name() = $placeholdersHead]" >    
    <xsl:copy-of select="dme:databaseFile('movement')//*[@xml:id = name(current())]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: $placeholdersHead contains sequences of strings, dme:databaseFile() returns a document node.

**Current output**:

```
<mei xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei">
    <respStmt>
        <corpName xml:id="NMA-editors" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <persName authURI="http://d-nb.info/gnd" authority="GND" codedval="119177978" label="MI-PID_58333" role="Editor" xml:id="HoLa">Howard Chandler Robbins Landon</persName>
        </corpName>
    </respStmt>
</mei>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like solved it by adding

```
copy-namespaces="no"
```

to the `<xsl:copy-of/>`

The output is

```
<mei xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei">
    <respStmt>          
        <corpName xml:id="NMA-editors">
            <persName authURI="http://d-nb.info/gnd" authority="GND" codedval="119177978" label="MI-PID_58333" role="Editor" xml:id="HoLa">Howard Chandler Robbins Landon</persName>
        </corpName>
    </respStmt>
</mei>
```

And the node

```
<corpName/>
```

is in the namespace `xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei"`